# wookmark plugin including grid as javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question about the topic.
I use stackover at the first time.

I use JS wookmark plugin. by the way I make web pages.
One of pages with sidebar with open and close. 
When I close the left sidebar, It makes a space left of article.
Usually It resizes width on no space. The open sidebar size is 260px. The close size is 70.

I use these but no action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

           var article_list = $("#grid-container article").get();
            var outer = $('<div class="grid-outer"></div>').get(0);
            var nowbox = false;

            for ( var i = 0; i < article_list.length; i++ ) {
                if($(article_list[i]).hasClass('area')){
                    nowbox = false;
                    $(outer).append(article_list[i]);
                }
                if($(article_list[i]).hasClass('area-box')) {
                    if(!nowbox) {
                        nowbox = $('<div class="gridbox"></div>').get(0);
                        $(outer).append(nowbox);
                    }
                    $(nowbox).append(article_list[i]);
                }
            }
            $("#grid-container").empty();
            $("#grid-container").append(outer);
            var options = {
              offset: 20, // Optional, the distance between grid items
              autoResize: true,
              fillEmptySpace: true,
            };

            var resizeTimer = null;
            var gridarr = [];
            var gridboxlist = $('.gridbox').get();
            for ( var i = 0; i < gridboxlist.length; i++ ) {
                gridarr[i] = new Wookmark( gridboxlist[i], options);
            }

            resize();
            resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                resize();
            }, 0);

            $(window).resize(function(){
                clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
                resize();
                resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    resize();
                }, 0);
            })

            function resize(){
                var gridboxlist = $('.gridbox').get();

                $(gridboxlist).each(function(){
                    var window_w = window.outerWidth;
                    var outer_w = $(this).width();
                    if( window_w < 1400) {
                        var w = Math.floor((( outer_w - ( 20 * 1 )) / 2));
                        $(this).find('.area-box').css({
                            'width': w+'px'
                        });
                    } else {
                        var w = Math.floor((( outer_w - ( 20 * 2 )) / 3));
                        $(this).find('.area-box').css({
                            'width': w+'px'
                        });
                    }

                });
                if( 0 < gridarr.length ){
                    refresh();
                }
            }

            function refresh(){
                for ( var i = 0; i < gridarr.length; i++ ) {
                    gridarr[i].layout(true);
                }
            }
});
```